# Why func2() prints out 10 instead of 12? How to call function and let it run?

Tags: python

```
def func1():
    Num = 3
    print(Num)
```

```
def func2():
    global Num
    Double_num = Num*2
    Num = 6
    print(Double_num)
```

How can I actually run it? Not sure how to call a function. And the answer says func2 prints out 10, why is it not 12?

Comment: Python is case sensitive. You can't write `Def` instead of `def`, and `Num` and `num` are different things.

Comment: You haven't shared the whole code. The output of `func2` depends on what the value of the `global variable` Num is. If Num = 5 the Double_num = 10, if Num = 6, Double_num = 12

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1: Don't use globals unless you absolutely need to and know exactly what you're doing, because you probably don't need them.

```
def func1():
    Num = 3
    print(Num)
    return Num

def func2():
    Num = func1()
    Double_num = Num*4
    print(Double_num)

func1()
func2()
```

Here's a full example which should print `3` and then `12`. When you use `def` that defines a function, but the code in that function doesn't execute unless you call the function, like `func1()`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable num has been predefined as 5 that's why when you call func2 it results in 10.
And func2() , is how you call the function